# What relation should i create in models so that one user can create only one comments for Product?

Tags: python, django, django-models, relational-database, relationship

This is my models. What is the best approach?
OneToOneField allows to create only one comments for all time.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=512,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=512,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = SlugField()
    name = NameField()
    description = DescriptionField()
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# You can use 'unique_together' feature of model

class Product(models.Model):
    slug = SlugField()
    name = NameField()
    description = DescriptionField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("person", "product")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is multiple comments per User, and multiple comments per Product. However, you need to ensure uniqueness for users and products inside comments. This can be achieved using `unique_together` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['person', 'product']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add `Product` to `Comment` as well:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['person', 'product']
```